# Python IndexError: list out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the python script written as :

```
import csv
with open ("ann.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    collected = []
    for row in reader:
        collected.append(row[0])
    print (",".join(collected))
```

ann.csv file as :

```
colums_header
7432
7849
7844
7108
8712
7833
7842
8723
7895
8719
9899
7352
7515
7252
8906
continued
```

When I try to run the python script it gives error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "columnTorow.py", line 6, in <module>
    collected.append(row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why am I getting the out of range exception?

Comment: Probably because you have an empty line in the file (perhaps at the end). You could have just used a generator expression: `','.join(row[0] for row in reader)` - if you have empty lines you could provide a guard, e.g. `','.join(row[0] for row in reader if row)`

Comment: just print `row` value inside `for` loop, I think some where in input file empty row is present. Problem in input csv, not in python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you have an empty line somewhere in the middle of the file or at the end of the file. You should add a condition checking before adding the item to your list like this:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        collected.append(row[0])
```

Hope this helps.